# How to build an AR application for a custom board running Android 7+?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm trying to find a foolproof workflow for implementing augmented reality (AR) applications on a kiosk-style device, which has custom hardware running Android 7 or higher. The manufacturer of the hardware advised me to pre-plan the AR development workflow since there might be hurdles in developing AR applications for interactive displays as compared to mobile devices.

Now, Google ARCore provides a list of supported devices [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices). All of these are mobile devices and tablets, which further raises suspicions about whether AR portions of the app will reliably run on the kiosk-style device I wish to build it on.

In case there is any confusion, I am trying to build something like [HeroMirror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tzx1A6jj1Ik) or [Magic Mirror](https://www.magicmirror.me/Apps/3D-Virtual-Dressing). As far as the information is readily available, these devices are Windows-based, and I am trying to build using Android. My end application is quite different, of course.

Any help regarding the following would be greatly appreciated:

- Overarching hardware and software requirements for developing AR for Android
- Hardware and software requirements for developing AR for Android on interactive displays
- Development tools and workflows for AR development for this situation
- Alternatives to ARCore which could be adapted to this situation

Thanks in advance!